# I am trying to host nginx using Kubernetes ReplicationController. Post successful hosting yet it is not reachable via the host system

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

**replicationcontroller.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**nginx-service.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

**Commands:**

1. kubectl create -f replicationcontroller.yml
2. kubectl create -f nginx-service.yml

[image: Kubernetes status]
[image: Not reachable via host system on port 31078]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error; the manifest works for me.

However, if you're using Minikube, you should be aware that Minikube has it's own virtual machine with IP address. Please try:

```
curl $(minikube ip):31078
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me too. I had to use minikube's IP address and not localhost.